# import data to mysql from azure sql

Tags: mysql, azure-sql-database

I got the following message:

```
I already have the request in to pull a create/insert script for the current 
database for you.  As soon as it’s done, I’ll send it over in an archive file.  
It’ll be from the Azure SQL export, so you will have to massage the queries in 
order to run it on a MySQL box, but it should work.
```

I've never worked with Azure SQL and was wondering if someone could tell me what I would need to do to run the script for a MySQL database

Comment: When you say Azure SQL are you referring to Azure Database for MySQL or Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Azure SQL.  I think I’m going to get an sql export script.

Comment: But you can use SSMA instead. It is the recommended method.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/migrating-mysql-databases-to-sql-server-azure-sql-db-mysqltosql